# display the Month, 'January' in the Month column of my result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to display the month, 'January' in the month column of my result.

```
SELECT Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
       FORMAT(Month(Transaction_Date),'Y') AS Month,
       CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
GROUP BY Month(Transaction_Date)
```

This is what I have tried, however it gives me a NULL result in the month column.

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `DATENAME`

```
SELECT 
  Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
  DATENAME(month,Transaction_Date) AS "Month",
  CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
GROUP BY Month(Transaction_Date)
```

Comment: SELECT 
  Month(Transaction_Date) AS Month_Number,
  DATENAME(MONTH, MONTH(Transaction_Date)) AS 'Month',
  CONCAT('$', SUM(Credit_Amount)) AS Total_Income
FROM Income 
GROUP BY 
MONTH(Transaction_Date)

I tried this code and it just displays January, whereas I want the subsequent months to display too.

Comment: Check your data.... if so, it's because you just have January data in your records.